# marked with gfm: true not rendering tables with appropriate css

Tags: css, css-tables, github-flavored-markdown, javascript-marked

I'm having these options to configure my `marked` object but the tables are not getting rendered with proper css.

```
{
        gfm: true,
        tables: true,
        breaks: false,
        pedantic: false,
        sanitize: false,
        smartLists: true,
        xhtml: false,
        smartypants: true,
        langPrefix: 'hljs language-',
        highlight(code) {
            return hljs.highlightAuto(code, ['html', 'javascript', 'java']).value;
        },
    }
```

Is there anything that I'm missing?
Is there a `min.css` file that I need to include in `index.html` to make this work and have proper css for tables?

The table is getting rendered as follows:

[image]

The corresponding markdown is:

```
| ID | Name| email |
|:----:|:----:|:----:|
| ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem got solved after including `gfm.min.css`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/pixelbrackets/gfm-stylesheet/dist/gfm.min.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Including the below CSS will resolve the issue.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/pixelbrackets/gfm-stylesheet/dist/gfm.min.css" />
```

But it may not be the best option for most of us as it has global styles which will affect your whole website.

---

To overcome this issue, consider using the appropriate CSS from here:

- https://github.com/sindresorhus/github-markdown-css
- https://cdnjs.com/libraries/github-markdown-css

It will allow you to apply styles only to the elements with the `markdown-body` class instead of affecting the whole website.